# How to save images in Google storage bucket with a rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-cloud-platform, rails-activestorage, rake-task

I have a Rails application using Active Storage, with some tasks that should run every day to attach images to a model and store them in a bucket in Google Cloud.

When I run the task "`rake attach_image:attach_image_to_cloud`" to attach the image, it shows:

```
Google::Cloud::PermissionDeniedError: forbidden: attach-images-app@attach-images.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.

Caused by:
Google::Apis::ClientError: forbidden: attach-images-app@attach-images.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.
```

I followed "[Setting up Rails 5.2 Active Storage, using Google Cloud Storage and Heroku](https://medium.com/@pjbelo/setting-up-rails-5-2-active-storage-using-google-cloud-storage-and-heroku-23df91e830f8)" and think I did everything right.

My Ruby version is 2.5.3 and Rails is 5.2.2.

My task is:

```
def download_data(download_url, datetime, json_data)
  puts "Downloading fields"
  @field = Field.new(datetime: datetime, json_data: json)
  puts "Saving field, datetime: #{datetime}"
  attach_image(download_url, datetime, @field)
  @field.save
  puts "Finished downloading #{datetime} field"
end

def attach_image(download_url, datetime, field)
  link = download_url
  field.image.attach(io: open(link), filename: "global_#{datetime}.png")
end

download_data(download_url, some_datetime, json_data)
```

This is my model field.rb:

```
class Field < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :image
end
```

This is my config.yml:

```
google:
  service: GCS
  project: attach-images
  credentials: <%= ENV['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'].as_json %>
  bucket: fields
google_dev:
  service: GCS
  project: attach-images
  credentials: <%= Rails.root.join("config/secrets/attach_images.json") %>
  bucket: fields
```

These are on my development.rb and production.rb environment files:

```
config.active_storage.service = :google_dev

config.active_storage.service = :google
```

I ran `bundle install` with:

```
gem "google-cloud-storage", "~> 1.8", require: false
```

My bucket and my service account key were both created correctly and the credential has owner rule. The credential is a hash downloaded when it was created in Google Cloud's console and set correctly in my development and Heroku production environments.

Comment: Are the credentials you provide via `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` working properly in development? And are you sure that in Heroku you have the correct value set  in that env variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution for this issue. The problem was solved by using the gsutil cors command to configure CORS on a bucket.

```
gsutil cors set [JSON_FILE_NAME].json gs://[BUCKET_NAME]
```

And the content of the json file was:

```
[
  {
    "origin": ["*"],
    "responseHeader": ["Content-Type", "Content-Md5", "Origin", "X-Requested-With", "Accept", "Authorization"],
    "method": ["PUT", "GET", "HEAD", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```